# issue with WP-API authentication

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I have a wordpress page from which I am trying to create a post using the WP AJAX REST API. My expectation is that if the user is already logged in the auth cookie will be in place and I'll be able to do the AJAX POST with the user's context. Yet I'm getting an error that the user is not authorized. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Are you using wordpress.com or a plugin on your own site? if wp.com https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/%24site/posts/new/

Comment: self hosted wordpress, JSON API plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

Comment: im not too familiar with that plugin but the documentation states that a nonce is required. It prob dosen't check for logged in status as the rest plugins are usually not designed for ajax calls from within the site (there is a core system for ajax)  https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#Method:-create_post

Comment: what does this mean? how should I call `wp_nonce_field`?

nonce - available from the get_nonce method (call with vars controller=posts and method=create_post)

I'm doing `wp_nonce_field('posts', 'create_post')`

Comment: added a answer below. I was wrong earlier this plugin does check if the user is logged in as well (needs to have edit_posts permission)

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is not kept up to date but adding a new post should work as follows:

1. `Go to the settings -> json api` and activate posts controller
2. get nonce

   `http://www.example.com/?json=core.get_nonce&controller=posts&method=create_post&callback=?`
3. Grab the nonce from the reponse, Response should be:

   `?({"status":"ok","controller":"posts","method":"create_post","nonce":"38nonce84"})`

4.Post a post

```
www.example.com/?json=posts.create_post&nonce=383nonce84&title=newpost&content=blahblabh&status=publish
```